# Looking for a logic to keep a fraction in a range

Tags: math, netlogo, fractions, agent-based-modeling, tax

I need to write some code that can calculate a variable which shows the preference of a consumer to buy a component for his laptop. The preference changes by the tax (`T`) and the importance of prices on people's purchases (`PriceI`). I need to include both `T` and `PriceI` to find the person's willingness (`W`) for purchasing a laptop. Tax changes in a slider ranging from `50 Cent` to `$6` . I want to keep the variable `W` in a range from `1 to 2`, where `1` is when the tax is on its default, minimum values which is `50 cent`.

So There are `2 variables` that have influence on `W`:

```
50<T<600
0.6 < PriceI < 9
```

Since I want `1<W<2`, I thought it should work if I first normalize all the data by dividing them by their max, then in order to find a fraction to be between 1 and 2, I made the numerator to be less than 4 and the denominator to be less than 2, hoping to have the result between 1 to 2 :

```
    to setup-WCalculator
ask consumers [
 set PP ((PriceI / 9) * 2)
  set TT ((T / 600) * 4) 
  set W TT / PP 
]

end
```

However, Netlogo makes both `PP` and `TT` zero while they should be a small value like 0.15! Does the logic for finding W make sense?
Thanks,

Comment: Since NetLogo uses floating point for all numeric values and calculations, I don't see how you can get zero from `((PriceI / 9) * 2` unless `PriceI` is indeed zero.  Have you checked for that?

Comment: As you discussed, the problem was not because of the way netlogo deals with numbers. Also the variables were given values inside the program.  I had defined a procedure `setup-WCalculator`, and inside another procedure, I was using `W`. It seems it was not working this way, and because it could not go into that procedure, a default zero made them zero. What I did that worked was that I called `setup-WCalculator` before the other procedure which was using  `W`. It seems to be working now. I had not noticed this way of normalizing you mentioned and using that made the results improve. Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Normalization is normally done with a formula such as

```
TT  = (T - Tmin) / (Tmax - Tmin)
```

or here

```
TT = (T - 50) / (600 - 50)
```

That gives a normalized value between 0 and 1 as T ranges between 50 and 600. If you want TTT to range between 1 and x, where x is > 1, then you can set

```
TTT = 1.0 + TT * (x - 1.0)
```

So

```
TTT = 1.0 + TT * (4.0 - 1.0) = 1.0 + TT * 3.0
```

will give you a value between 1 and 4.

Comment: Is your answer that the question is mistaken and that he cannot be getting zero? A comment to confirm that may have been a good idea before answering.

Comment: Yes. That should have been a comment and the normalizing an answer. I've edited the response accordingly.  Thanks.